# WPF Designer unable to find SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sqlite, xaml

In my WPF application a seperate class-library is used to persist session-data to a SQLite-database. I ran into the [well known problem](https://www.google.de/search?q=sqlite.interop%20not%20found) of the SQLite.Interop.dll not being found, after adding the class-library-dll to my WPF-project. I manually added x86/x64-dlls to the project and installed the SQLite nuget-packages to the wpf-project as well, the application is running fine now.

However the VS WPF-Designer is still unable to display views that utilize my class-library and crashes with "SQLite.Interop.dll not found". This obviously 'limits' my ability to change the design of the views. Any ideas on how to provide the designer with the desired dll??

This is not a duplicate of the numerous posts about the SQLite.Interop-dependency, as my problem is solely related to the WPF-designer in Visual-Studio.

Comment: So is this error while publishing the application?

Comment: no, its not. The problem occurs during design-time. The application deploys and runs just fine

Comment: with kindest regards to the downvote-army, :D:D

Comment: Same problem but with a 3rd party control.  I gave up trying to fix it, and use d:IsHidden="True" as a workaround so while I no longer see the control in the designer, the errors are gone as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware of d:IsHidden but meanwhile we found another workaround that will leave the control/view visible: in the code-behind of the control we check for the designer-process using

System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(
    DependencyObjectXYZ())

and if design-mode is detected prevent the init-call to the external .dll. but this might only work in our specific case..

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, copy the x86 version of SQLite.Interop.dll to the Visual Studio IDE folder. For a default installation of Visual Studio 2019 Community, the path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE".